# Change style after a d3 path has been clicked

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I stop the path style being changed if the path has been clicked? I want path style to not be changed after `pathHover` has been clicked.

```
let pathHover = this.svg.append('path')
    .data([data])
    .attr('class', 'line-padded')
    .attr('d', line);

pathHover.on('mouseover', function() {
    console.log('path mouse over');
    path.style('stroke-width', 6);
});

pathHover.on('mouseleave', function() {
    path.style('stroke-width', 4);
});

pathHover.on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    path.style('stroke', 'blue');
    path.style('stroke-width', 6);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this. Since the first D in DDD (also known as D3) means *data*, the approach I like most is binding a datum to the clicked element, indicating that it was clicked:

```
d.clicked = true;
```

Or, if you want to reverse the boolean after a second click:

```
d.clicked = !d.clicked;
```

Then, in the `mouseover`, just check that datum:

```
if (d.clicked) return;
```

Here is a demo using green circles: if you mouse over them, they turn red. If you click them, they turn blue, and never turn red (or green) again.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(5).map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d
    }
  }))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cursor", "pointer")
  .attr("cy", 75)
  .attr("cx", d => 30 + 50 * d.x)
  .attr("r", 20)
  .style("fill", "lime");

circles.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  if (d.clicked) return;
  d3.select(this).style("fill", "firebrick")
}).on("mouseout", function(d) {
  if (d.clicked) return;
  d3.select(this).style("fill", "lime")
}).on("click", function(d) {
  d.clicked = !d.clicked;
  d3.select(this).style("fill", "blue")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a few tactics, either

set `path.style("pointer-events", "none")` for clicked paths, which will stop all future clicks/mouseover events.

Or if that is too drastic, add a class to clicked paths `path.classed("clicked", true)`, which you could use in a test during your mouseover event before applying any styling changes