# Tracking d3 data on click events

Tags: d3.js

If a path is clicked I set a clicked property how can I check that property when the svg is clicked.

```
this.svg = this.selectorElement.append('svg')
                               .on('click', function(d) {
                                   console.log('svg clicked');
                                   for (let path of dataPaths) {

                                   }
                               });
```

Set the property here

```
pathHover.on('click', function(d) {
         d.clicked = !d.clicked;
         d3.event.stopPropagation();
      });

dataPaths.push(pathHover);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you had already set the property to that element's datum and that the variable refers to just one element, you can get the property using:

```
pathHover.datum().clicked;
```

For instance, storing it in a variable, which will be `false` or `true`:

```
var isClicked = pathHover.datum().clicked;
```

I said *"provided that you had already set the property"* because, according to my answer to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46576958/5768908), the property is set only when the user clicks the element. If you kept that approach, the snippet above will return `undefined` if you click the SVG before clicking the element.

Alternatively, if you have several elements, just `filter()` your selection according tho the property, dropping that `for` loop.